# call to undefined method problem in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I am inserting a variable called "creditCheck" into a twig template called **node--course.html.twig**

I start in a class caled **FormaRegis** which extedns a abstract class called **FormaEntity**

This is the function:

```
namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;


class FormaRegis extends FormaEntity {
.
.
.
public function completionCheck() {
        $check = false;

         if (parent::accessCheck()) {
            $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM learning_courseuser
                    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(date_complete,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    AND idUser =  " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'];

            return $sql;
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }
}
```

In abstract class **FormaEntity** I have this function which is supposed to take the sql string from the previous function, **completionCheck()** and executes the mysql query and returns and object. Here is the function:

```
namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

abstract class FormaEntity {
.
.
.
public function getCCresult() {
       if ($this->completionCheck() == "") {
          \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
          return false;
       }

       $result = $this->connection->query($this->completionCheck())->fetch();
         \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();

       if ($result > 5 ) {
         $check = "fail";
       }
       else {
         $check = "pass";
       }

       return $check;
    }
```

In another class called **FormaNotification** which also extends **FormaEntity** write function that will be able to calls the function **getCCresult()** from the abstract class **FormaEntity**
This is the function:

```
namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;

class FormaNotification extends FormaEntity {
.
.
.
public function getCreditResult() {

         return parent::getCCresult();
    }
```

Lastly in my .theme file I wrote a function called **txhs_preprocess_node__course(&$variables)** which calls the previous function and is supposed to fetch the information I retrived from the database. But it does not. Here is my theme function:

```
use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaNotification;
use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaMyCourse;
use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaRegis;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
.
.
.
function txhs_preprocess_node__course(&$variables) {

  $noti = new FormaNotification();
  var_dump($noti->getCreditResult());
  exit;

  if ($noti->completionCheck() == "fail") {
      $check = "fail";
  }
  else {
    $check = "pass";
  }
   // $variables['creditCheck'] = "HI";

}
```

I have tried a whole slew of things such as renaming the functions, moving the functions around the theme file...but I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am running php 7.2.11, with mysql 5.0.12 with drupal 8.5.6

I expect an out to be an object with a number, but instead i get an error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\docebo_login\FormaNotification::completionCheck() in Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity->getCCresult() (line 106 of modules/custom/docebo_login/src/FormaEntity.php).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187079/discussion-on-question-by-mat-steuernagle-call-to-undefined-method-problem-in-dr).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have a base class & 2 subclasses:

- `abstract class FormaEntity` > `FormaRegis`
- `abstract class FormaEntity` > `FormaNotification`

When calling `getCreditResult()` on `new FormaNotification()` it fails because the first line in `FormaEntity::getCCresult()` is calling a method that doesn't exist in that abstract class, being `completionCheck()`. A little further down, `$noti->completionCheck()`, would also fail for the same reason.

AFAICT from your code, the `completionCheck()` is only specified in `FormaRegis`, which is causing your issue. The parent class and neither `FormaNotification` have access to that.